# How to combine formtastic with Ajax form submission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, formtastic

I would like to use formtastic instead of standard Rails helpers for my forms, however I currently submit them using Ajax (with `remote_form_for`). I suppose I could use the jQuery form plugin to Ajax-ify formtastic forms, but would it be the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you get your form working great without Ajax, then apply the extra functionality unobtrusively with Javascript, you'll have the best of both worlds.  The `remote_form_for` option is removed or deprecated from Rails 3, but they have added a `form_for ... :remote => true` option which Formtastic will support when we merge in Rails 3 support (planned for 1.1).

Comment: Thanks for your response Justin, I'm looking forward to using formtastic, looks like it will make my form code nicer.

Answer (score 1):

If you need add and remove fields (nested forms or attributes) functionality for you models — use **cocoon** gem with formtastic